# VBA Error Run time error 9 Subscript Out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting Run time error 9

```
Sub Conway()
Dim aRng As Range
Dim Data As Range, c As Collection
Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
Set c = New Collection
    Path = "D:\InTransit DR Report\"
    RawFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Please Select InTransit Raw WorkBook:")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If RawFile = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Please select appropriate Final Output file", vbCritical, "Nike InTransit DR Automation"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open RawFile, True, False
    Application.Wait (10)
    Application.Visible = False
    Application.Visible = True
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    End If
    Sheets("In-Transit").Select 'Getting error here
```

Comment: Do you have a sheet that is called, *exactly*, "In-Transit"?

Comment: Check this: [Subscript out of range (Error 9)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx) to resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes I do have the Sheet Named In-Transit in the target file

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with **two** workbooks:

1. the workbook containing the macro *(wb1)*
2. the workbook opened by the macro *(wb2)*

Once *wb2* has been opened, it becomes the `Active` workbook and the line:

```
Sheets("In-Transit").Select
```

will only work if that sheet is in *wb2*.  If the sheet is in the original workbook *(wb1)*, that workbook must be re-activated beforre the sheet can be `Selected`.  Also make sure that there are no extra spaces in the sheetname.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs the error has caught & corrected the code.